# How to completely remove Xcode 9 beta after installing released Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have installed Xcode 9 released version from AppStore. but I already have older beta version of Xcode 9 which consuming around 10 GB space.

I want to remove that older version, but don't know proper way to do it and doubt about if my working projects get affected by doing that or not.

Comment: can i simply move to trash that older version???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drag the Xcode-Beta app from /Applications to the trash bin as when deleting other files or apps. It will not affect your projects.

Answer (score 2):

If you see the following message

> The item “Xcode-beta” can’t be moved to the Bin because some of its extensions are in use.

You can do the following:

1. `Right click on Xcode and click on "Show package contents".`
2. `Go to Contents->PlugIns`
3. `Delete PlugIns`
4. `Now go back to where your` **Xcode** `is and delete Xcode`

Alternatively, if you have only one Xcode version on you mac, and want to delete it completely, you can run the following command

`sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`

Answer (score 1):

Trying just delete XCode beta app moving it into trash but getting system message: "Unable to remove "XCode-beta.app" because some part of its extensions is in use now"

Answer (score 0):

Follow below step :

```
1. Right click on Xcode 
2. Select Show Package Contents
3. Open contents 
4. Delete Plugins folder
5. Now delete Xcode
```